# How to prevent grid popup editor from closing on update and create on kendo ui for angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm using kendo ui grid for angular with popup editing form.I want to not close edit form when I click on save button.

This https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uugx2s is my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function onCancel for controlling if data is valid or not.
Please check the example on the Dialogs section: 
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/dialog/action-buttons/